# Blender opens, then crashes

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

Ok so, I have blender 2.73 and I open it. i see a glimpse of the gui, then it crashes.
Help?

Thanks in Advance!

Windows Vista 32 bit Ultimate
The console says:
Warning! Using result of ChoosePixelFormat.
Warning! Using result of ChoosePixelFormat.
found bundled python: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.73\python
Writing: C:\Users\FLAMIN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\blender.crash.txt

I've looked at all the other problems similar to this and still, blender crashes.

Tried it NoviceInDisguise and MarcClintDion

Comment: This sounds like you may not have GPU drivers installed.  Try upgrading them from the video card's website if you have not already done so.

Comment: You have completely uninstalled Blender and reinstalled, tried different builds, updated drivers, etc? All of those sorts of things?

Comment: tried it, doesn't do anything